# how to redirect in django through select option in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need help. I am makig a sign up page in django In my forms.py I have two select optins. option 1) free trial & option 2)monthly subscription I want user to go to login page if he selects option1 and to checkout page if he selects option2. here is my code.

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    CHOICES = (('Option 1', 'Free 30 days trial'),('Option 2', '$9.99 Monthly subscription'))
    plan = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', "plan", "password1", "password2"
```

views.py

```
def signupUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if plan == 'Free 30 days trial':
                form.save()
                return redirect("/main/login/")
            else:
                form.save()
                return redirect("/main/checkout/")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {"form":form})
```

but this gives error: `plan is not defined`

Need help please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't defined `plan` in the scope.

Change `plan` to `form.plan` since you are referring to the plan inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the data submitted with a form, once it has been successfully validated by calling `is_valid() (and is_valid() has returned True)`, the validated form data will be in the form.cleaned_data dictionary. This data will have been nicely converted into Python types for you.

Code in views.py goes like this

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            plan = form.cleaned_data['plan']
            print(plan)
            if plan == 'Option 1':
                return redirect("/main/login/")
            else:
                return redirect("/main/checkout/")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {"form":form})
```